# Integrating C++ code in PHP script

Tags: php, c++

I want to run a `C++` routine during a very simple `PHP` script. The index script is used to upload an image. The C++ then treats the image and saves it locally. Also a path to the image is generated. To do so I am using the following code:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['img']) && !empty($_POST['img']))
{
     $img = $_POST['img'];
     exec("exe {$img}",$output);
}
echo $data."<br>";
echo "<pre>", print_r($output), "</pre>";
?>
```

My question is, how can I access the path created in the `C++` routine from the `PHP` script. I have tried to `cout` and then check the `$output` variable, however the array was empty. I've also tried to edit the `argv[1]`, but this didn't work either. Does anyone know how or if this can be done?

Comment: if you do know the path (at least to folder) you can work a little around it. But maybe you can (from your c++ code) create a text file with the path and read it from php?

Comment: I haven't thought of that. But yeah, it is really simple actually. If I create the file in a specific path I just need to go and read it. Thanks!!!

Comment: Interesting question! In a project I'm working I'll need something like this! @Marco-Mura presented a solution that solves the problem but is this the best and unique solution? I think there must be (or at least should be) a more efficient way to do this without using text files.

Comment: @zedv maybe you can create an xml file (only one time). Each time you upload then you update the file. This way you can obtain something like a map of uploaded file. Otherwise you can as example use a Db to store those info.